# ArrayList behavior with and without adding an empty string

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, whitespace

A newly created `ArrayList` without adding any elements to it looks just like an `ArrayList` with an empty string added in it.

This makes me feel that a newly created `ArrayList` even without adding any elements in it has a default empty `string` or element added in it.

```
package cracking;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Ask
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println(al.size());//0
        System.out.println(al);//[]

        al.add("");
        System.out.println(al.size());//1
        System.out.println(al);//[]
    }
}
```

However, the discrepancy between the size of `ArrayList` in the two scenarios makes them inconsistent, especially since the two `ArrayList` when printed out look just the same.

To maintain consistency, I feel, either of two would've been good:

1. The size of the ArrayList which is just created, i.e., even before
   adding any element to it should show 1 implying empty string or
   element, since even adding to the `ArrayList` makes it look the same.
2. Printing out a newly created `ArrayList` should not be allowed, it
   should just print NULL or something instead of showing `[]` like it
   shows now

Comment: You are effectively inserting a string object that is empty. That will count as an entry in the ArrayList, even if it doesn't appear as such when it is printed. Remeber than an empty string is different than a NULL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are being tricked by the `toString` implementation of the `AbstractCollection`. See here:

```
public String More ...toString() {
   Iterator<E> i = iterator();
    if (! i.hasNext())
        return "[]";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append('[');
    for (;;) {
        E e = i.next();
        sb.append(e == this ? "(this Collection)" : e);
        if (! i.hasNext())
            return sb.append(']').toString();
        sb.append(", ");
    }
}
```

Your collection has a size of 1, but it's not printing anything, including the comma character `,` because it only has size one. Try adding multilpe emptry Strings and you'll see the result more clearly.

```
al.add("");
al.add("");
al.add("");
al.add("");
al.add("");
System.out.println(al); // Prints [, , , , ]
```

Comment: Moral of the story is: don't rely on `toString()` for the correctness of your code. It wasn't designed for it.

Comment: @Kon, thanks for showing me the implementation. I think this is the line which is the source of my confusion. if (! i.hasNext()) return "[]"; But don't you think it's not a good idea to show the same output with and without an empty string. Maybe they could've output if (! i.hasNext()) return ""; or something of that sort. What do you think?

Comment: @PepperBoy Keep in mind that the implementation is `inherited` by `ArrayList`. This implementation needs to be consistent across all `Collection` classes (`Set`, `Map`, etc..). In this case the implementation makes sense because you will never want to do something like `list1.toString().equals(list2.toString())` because that comparison is awkward. More likely you want to do something like `list1.equals(list2)`. The `toString()` method is designed to give a meaningful representation of the object, but not a precisely unique one. That is, *two different lists may have identical toStrings*

Answer (score 2):

`[]` is representative of an empty list. This is by convention, but I think you'll find this reasonable.

And printing the `ArrayList` uses `toString` on each of the objects that it contains to show a printed representation of those contents. When a string is printed (using `toString`) the quotes *aren't* included.

Consider the following amendment to your code:

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

al.add("");
al.add("");
al.add("");
System.out.println(al);//[]
```

The output is:

```
[, , ]
```

We might just as well complain about the use of the brackets when printing an `ArrayList`, but note, that the output of `toString` is often only useful for debugging, and shouldn't be relied on programatically.

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) for `toString`:

> In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object. The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read.

In the case of your example, this *does* break down a bit: printing the `ArrayList<strin>` with a single empty `string` isn't particularly informative. If you need to check/validate the contents of your collection, e.g. for debugging, you should also print the `length`.

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList` is using the `toString` of the object that you place into it as part of its `toString` call.  The reason this appears odd to you is due to the fact that printing an empty string prints nothing.

Ideally, one would not elect to store an empty string in the list, and would instead do a check to ensure that only non-empty strings ever made their way into it.

```
if(!"".equals(value)) {
    al.add(value);
}
```